# python thread waits for input before it prints

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a socket communication program, I have a main thread, and another thread trying to sock.recv()

when it does recieve bytes, it works as it needs, it goes to the right function, which at the end prints, and then the thread listens again to bytes (as wanted).

the problem is that the program won't print until I press enter...

if it matters i'm getting input at the same time in the main thread but it shouldn't matter.

note - the bytes are sent like this:

int (4 bytes) - msg type (string to print is 2)

int (4 bytes) - length of text to print

string ( bytes) - actual text

full code:

```
import socket
import time
import struct
import threading
import sys

PORT = 54321

def try_to_connect(ip):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM,
                                      socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
    sock.settimeout(1)
    try:
        sock.connect((ip, PORT))
        return sock
    except:
        return False

def text_parse(text, msg_id):
    byte_text = bytes(text, "utf-8")
    return struct.pack("II%ds" % len(byte_text), msg_id, len(byte_text), byte_text)


def main(sock):
    global file_name
    print("connected succefuly. to run a command, write $<command> (no space)\nto request a file, enter file path.\nto exit this program enter exit.") 
    inputed_text = ''
    while True:
        inputed_text = input()
        if inputed_text == '':
            pass
        elif inputed_text == "exit":
            return
        elif inputed_text[0] == "$":
            sock.send(text_parse(inputed_text[1:], 0))
        else:
            file_name = inputed_text
            sock.send(text_parse(inputed_text, 1))


def print_string(message, msg_len):
    text = struct.unpack("%ds" % msg_len, message)[0].decode("utf-8")
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.flush()


def copy_file(message):
    global file_name
    final_file = open(file_name, "wb")
    final_file.write(message)
    final_file.close()    

def recieve_loop(sock):
    while True:
        try:
            header = sock.recv(8)
            if not header: break
            msg_type = struct.unpack("I", header[:4])[0]
            msg_len = struct.unpack("I", header[4:8])[0]
            print(msg_type)
            print(msg_len)
            message = sock.recv(msg_len)
            if msg_type == 2:
                print_string(message, msg_len)
            elif msg_type == 3:
                copy_file(message)
        except socket.timeout:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("welcome to remote desktop program.\nto connect to your computer, enter it's ip.\nto exit enter exit")
    text_input = "b,kjhkf"
    while True:
        text_input = input()
        if text_input == "exit":
            exit()
        else:
            sock = try_to_connect(text_input)
            if sock:
                socket_recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target = recieve_loop, args = [sock])
                socket_recieve_thread.start()
                main(sock)
                socket_recieve_thread.join()
            else:
                print("the computer is not online")
```

Comment: `data=sock.recv(buff); if data : if msg_type: #do_something`

Comment: @dsgdfg buff = ? and how will it help? can you be more informative?

Comment: buff = your buff is `4`, my opinion use higher value. 4 char only read `header of payload` where other msg parts ?

Comment: after it knows what message type it is (2), it goes to print_string() function, it recieves the rest of the data there. @dsgdfg

Comment: share the complete code

Comment: @NabeelAhmed done it